# Trying to get highchart example working on local machine

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm new to high charts / jquery and trying to just copy the html and js into two files on my local drive to see if I can get it to render in my broswer.

My basic question is how can I take one of the example code provided by high charts in jfiddle and get it to work on my local machine?

The sample code from highcharts.com works in jfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/m3MVk/

```
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y +'°C';
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});

});
```

HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Then in one folder i made two files:  chart1.js and chart1.html with the above code in them.

I also saved the most recent jquery into the folder as jquery-1.9.1.js
I then added  to the top of the html file.

When I load the HTML file in Chrome, nothing happens.

Can somebody please advise?

Comment: check for errors in console as a start...!

Comment: and do you have element with id "container" in your html ..?

Comment: Yes, i added the HTML above now.

Comment: Do you see any error in the console ?

Comment: @spoolup: if a provided answer(s) helped you (as it did in my case) it would be best to accept and upvote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

Use the code below and put it in a .html file (example: Chart.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Chart
    </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                title: {
                    text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: '°C'
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'middle',
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Tokyo',
                    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
                }, {
                    name: 'New York',
                    data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
                }, {
                    name: 'Berlin',
                    data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
                }, {
                    name: 'London',
                    data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Change the reference of the files below to your local files path

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

you should include jquery in your html file:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your html code doesn't show a reference to your own chart1.js file.

Comment: so that was my question.  in jfiddle it never loads in in the html either which I didn't understand....is this a special feature of jfiddle?  I also tried adding <script type="text/javascript" scr="file.js"></script> but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: jsFiddle will automatically include the script you type in the Javascript frame, into the result pane (it actually includes it straight into the head section of the created html doc).  In chrome you can inspect the pane and see the fully created html doc that resides inside of an iframe.
To your problem: Can you check the javascript console in chrome and see if you are getting any errors?